# Concourse : multiple steps on_failure

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, concourse

Is it possible to execute multiple tasks from on_failure in concourse? 
I could not find an example in documentation or elsewhere 
I'd like to do something like

`on_failure:
- aggregate:
  - put: slack-notification
  - put: mark-pr-as-failed`

Is this possible or should I create a new task combining both steps above?

Comment: Hello Harshal, the answer below is correct. Please accept it.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [do step](https://concourse-ci.org/do-step.html).

Here is an example in our pipeline: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/infrastructure-ci/blob/ad5e3a717bb191a09c99756ecbc158622e1caf9e/pipelines/bosh-bootloader.yml#L1970-L2001

Comment: link fix for do operator: https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#do-step

Comment: yet another link fix für do step: https://concourse-ci.org/do-step.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ["try" step](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#schema.step.try-step.try) so as not to fail the step at all?